# Copy from S3 to Redshift only specific files without manifest file process

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

I am using a current process where I upload manifest file into a series of folders on a weekly basis to copy data into redshift. This folder contains 92 .gzip files, 1 header file and 1 success file. It is loaded weekly as the data is overwritten to each folder on a weekly basis.

Issue: I have an Azure data pipe process picking up these .gzip files as well and if my manifest file is in the folder while the azure copy job runs it stops the Azure copy process.

---

My Need: To be able to copy all of the .gzip files ONLY - from the S3 folder without using a manifest file.

---

Current Copy:
`copy table from 's3://path/test_manifest.json'
iam_role 'arn:aws:iamXXXXX'
gzip
manifest;`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can put the manifest file in a different location (different bucket or different path within the same bucket). That works fine since the manifest file specifies where to find the files.

This should solve your problem with Azure failing when it sees the manifest file.